# UITableView image loading with json is not loading properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

I am using this to display some labels and images by JSON parsing in to tableView but images are not coming at the first launch when scrolling the tableview images are coming and dancing i mean not coming in order format help me with this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        self.customCellClass = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (self.customCellClass == nil)
        {
            self.customCellClass = [[CellCustom alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
        self.customCellClass.nameLabel.text = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]; // label
        self.customCellClass.cityLabel.text = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"region"]; // label

        NSString * stripped = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"summary"] stripHtml]; //label
        self.customCellClass.detailLabel.text = stripped;
        self.customCellClass.mainImage.image = nil;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"logo"]]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                self.customCellClass.mainImage.image = image;
            });
        });
        return self.customCellClass;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below code in `UITableView's` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
//Check if cell has image or not
if(!self.customCellClass.mainImage.image)
{
   dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
   dispatch_async(q, ^{

      NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"logo"]]];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data0];

      //Get main queue
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       /* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to be what we just fetched. */

       self.customCellClass.mainImage.image = image;

      });

   });
}
```

**Good solution** is if you are using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) then use `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"logo"]]
[self.customCellClass.mainImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: when app first launch image is empty after i scroll the tableview images are coming but not in proper order

Comment: i did not use any afnetworking framework is this good if i use AFNetworking framework

Comment: But in your whole project where you need to make http connection AFNetworking can be used.

Comment: what means "xctest/xctest.h class " not found it saying after dragging the AFNetworking folder in to the project

Comment: Drag AFNetworking and UIKit+AFNetworking folder in project and import #import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

Comment: Love You you saved me it is 100% working and one more thing i can also load the labels with AFNetworking ?

Comment: because it is little bit slower when the app launches cells are coming with data in slower

Comment: I hope you have removed dispatch_queue_t?. For UILabel there is no need of AFNetworking same as UIImageView as you will be having text data then only you will be using UITableView. My concern is your structure might be wrong which leads for slower display

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning image=nil every time when cell is loading and downloading the same image.

You can user following class to do this seamlessly.

AsyncImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AsyncImageView : UIView {
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSString *urlString; // key for image cache dictionary
}

-(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url;
-(void)loadBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image;
-(UIImage*)loadImageFromURLForGetIamge:(NSURL*)url;
-(BOOL)getCachedImageWithUrl:(NSString*)url;

@end
```

and AsyncImageView.m

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "ImageCacheObject.h"
#import "ImageCache.h"

//
// Key's are URL strings.
// Value's are ImageCacheObject's
//
static ImageCache *imageCache = nil;

#define SPINNY_TAG 5555   

@implementation AsyncImageView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [connection cancel];

}

-(void)loadBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

    //imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    [imageView setNeedsLayout]; 
    [self setNeedsLayout];

    imageView=nil;

}

-(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    if (connection != nil) {
        [connection cancel];
        connection = nil;
    }
    if (data != nil) {
        data = nil;
    }

    if (imageCache == nil) // lazily create image cache
        imageCache = [[ImageCache alloc] initWithMaxSize:2*1024*1024];  // 2 MB Image cache
  //  NSLog(@"Value of the url here = %@",url);
    urlString = [[url absoluteString] copy];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageForKey:urlString];
    if (cachedImage != nil)
    {
        if ([[self subviews] count] > 0)
        {
            [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cachedImage];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

        [self addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.frame = self.bounds;
        [imageView setNeedsLayout]; // is this necessary if superview gets setNeedsLayout?
        [self setNeedsLayout];

        imageView=nil;
        return;
    }


    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinny = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinny.tag = SPINNY_TAG;
    spinny.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-10, self.frame.size.height/2-10, 20, 20);
    spinny.center = self.center;
    [spinny startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:spinny];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:spinny];

    spinny=nil;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                         timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}


-(BOOL)getCachedImageWithUrl:(NSString*)url
{
    BOOL isIamgeCached=NO;

    if (imageCache == nil)
        imageCache = [[ImageCache alloc] initWithMaxSize:2*1024*1024];  // 2 MB Image cache

    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageForKey:url];
    if (cachedImage != nil)
    {
        isIamgeCached=YES;
    }
    return isIamgeCached;
}


-(UIImage*)loadImageFromURLForGetIamge:(NSURL*)url
{
    if (connection != nil)
    {
        [connection cancel];
        connection = nil;
    }
    if (data != nil)
    {
        data = nil;
    }

    if (imageCache == nil) // lazily create image cache
        imageCache = [[ImageCache alloc] initWithMaxSize:2*1024*1024];  // 2 MB Image cache
    //  NSLog(@"Value of the url here = %@",url);
    urlString = [[url absoluteString] copy];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageForKey:urlString];
    if (cachedImage != nil)
    {
        if ([[self subviews] count] > 0)
        {
            [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cachedImage];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        imageView.autoresizingMask =
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.frame = self.bounds;
        [imageView setNeedsLayout]; // is this necessary if superview gets setNeedsLayout?
        [self setNeedsLayout];

        imageView=nil;
        return cachedImage;
    }


    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinny = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinny.tag = SPINNY_TAG;
    spinny.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-10, self.frame.size.height/2-10, 20, 20);
    //spinny.center = self.center;
    [spinny startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:spinny];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:spinny];

    spinny=nil;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:20.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    return cachedImage;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data==nil)
    {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection
{
    connection = nil;

    UIView *spinny = [self viewWithTag:SPINNY_TAG];
    [spinny removeFromSuperview];

    if ([[self subviews] count] > 0)
    {
        [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [imageCache insertImage:image withSize:[data length] forKey:urlString];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    [imageView setNeedsLayout]; // is this necessary if superview gets setNeedsLayout?
    [self setNeedsLayout];

    imageView=nil;
    data = nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `dispatch_async` to load image from remote, that means the images to be  displayed in tableview cells are loaded asynchronously. And you use a instance variable to record current cell, which cause the problem you met.

After a image being loaded finished (may take few minutes), it want to be displayed in a cell (written in this code),

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    self.customCellClass.mainImage.image = image;
});
```

only to find that the `self.customCellClass` points to a wrong cell (the `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` was called several times during the image being loaded, and each calling changes the pointing of `self.customCellClass` to other cell).

So, the order of images is wrong.

Try this:

Use a locality variable to keep the cell get from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CellCustom *customCellClass = (CellCustom *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (customCellClass == nil)
    {
        customCellClass = [[CellCustom alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    customCellClass.nameLabel.text = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]; // label
    customCellClass.cityLabel.text = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"region"]; // label

    NSString * stripped = [[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"summary"] stripHtml]; //label
    customCellClass.detailLabel.text = stripped;
    customCellClass.mainImage.image = nil;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"logo"]]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data0];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            customCellClass.mainImage.image = image;
        });
    });
    return customCellClass;
}
```

Besides, take a look at the difference between `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` and `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: can you please tell me what i have to change

Comment: yes i tried it but it is not worked for me so i used AFNetworking framework now every thing is working fine for me

Comment: sorry i did not try give me a sec

Comment: nope it is not working for me images are coming in very bad manner they are jumping to another locating any i got solution with afnetworking framework thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Why not try SDWebImage？@MaheshM

Comment: I dont now about that but definatle i will try  that

Comment: help me what to do SDWebimage How to do